# Google chrome devtool : Code hint not working for snippet

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, javascript-objects, javascript-framework, javascript-debugger

In google chrome Dev-tool, snippet does not show code hint/autocomplete. But it only works in the console.
To give more background, there are few js files loaded in the browser. When the function in js is accessed from the console, it shows code hint(check the 1st link). But the same thing does not work in the snippet(check the 2nd link)

Console code hint/autocomplete works:
[image: ChromeConsolAutocomplete]

Code in Snippet only show local variable :[image: ChromeSnippetNoAutocomplete]

But when code in snippet is executed, correct output is shown:[image: ChromeSnippetOutputInConsole]

This means it takes context. So, is there any way to enable code hint/autocomplete in the snippet?

If no then please guide me to create chrome extension for it.

Some sample code will be a great help.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: It's not implemented. I think it's inherently impossible to implement since the snippet doesn't have any active execution context at the time of writing as opposed to console. You can suggest Chrome to consider implementing it anyway on https://crbug.com.

Comment: Is there any way to implement using chrome extension ???

Comment: You can write your own editor based on CodeMirror or Ace and so on, which will be shown in a separate devtools panel.